# Highlight text based on list in R shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, stringr, formattable

I would like to highlight/color part of a string based on a list in R shiny. I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

      mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
          box(title="text",status="primary", solidHeader = TRUE, align = "left", width = 4,
              verbatimTextOutput("text"))))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$text <- renderText({

     print("ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRS")

   })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I color/highlight parts of the string using a list:

```
highlight <- c("GHIJ", "MNOP", "STUV")
```

The list changes based on user input.

EDIT: I was able to highlight specific parts of the string using the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(tableHTML)


ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      box(title="Sequence",status="primary", solidHeader = TRUE, align = "left", width = 6,
        htmlOutput("text")),
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#text {word-break: break-all;}")))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderText({

    text2 <- c("ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRS") 
    text2 %<>% stringr::str_replace_all(c('MNOPQR' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">MNOPQR</span>'))




    print(text2)

  })
}
```

I have a big list of strings that I want to highlight that changes based on the user input. I want to wrap the str_replace_all function into a loop looking up all strings in the list.

Something like this:

```
words <- c("ABCD", "MNOP", "GHIJ")

    for (word in words){

    text2 %<>% stringr::str_replace_all(c('word' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">word</span>'))

    }
```

but I do not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are a few steps here. First is to find the strings that need to be highlighted using grep, then split the original string and finally apply an html tag, for instance

```
tags$span(style="color:red", x)
```

for red color.